# What are the differences between Visual Studio 2012 Professional with MSDN and Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msdn

I am planning to buy Visual Studio 2012 Professional, but I see two options:
Visual Studio 2012 Professional **with MSDN** and Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

What are the extra features of Visual Studio 2012 Professional **with MSDN?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other things With MSDN you get Azure (cloud) credits, access to developer licenses for most Microsoft OSes (great for testing) and you have the ability to download all past Visual Studio products (2010, 2005 etc) as well as future ones. Future being - new releases of VS that come out during your subscription period. MSDN subscribers use to get updates on CDs/DVDS in quarterly shipments (via snail mail) although MS is dropping that. All downloads will be online.

The only thing I don't know is if Visual Studio 2012 with MSDN entitles you to use Visual Studio Online (effectively you do development in the cloud). I believe it does but don't quote me on that.

If you don't need access to OSes for testing, don't need to get newer versions of Visual Studio (or get past ones) then it might not be worth the money.

Comment: Thank you Micheal! Now it is clear that I only need Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I am using it only for experimenting.